# Unable to commit my project to github

Tags: github

> > I am using Gitbash to commit my project but I am getting the below
> >     error and the repository which I am getting in fatal error is not the
> >     remote repository to which I am doing a commit.
> >     I want to change this repo

```
    $ git push -u origin master
    Fatal: HttpRequestException encountered.
    Username for 'https://github.com': 4bhishekKasam
    remote: Repository not found.
    fatal: repository 'https://github.com/4bhishekKasam/Authentication-using-Passportjs.gi/' not found
```

Comment: I believe all repo name should be ending with ".git" but your repo name is ".gi". Also I don't see such repo in your github account. Is that private repo? Is it like you have given wrong repo name or deleted repo from Github?

Comment: It was earlier repo. now I created new repo still i am unable to commit

Comment: Give a try to update your remote URL to new repo. `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/4bhishekKasam/YourNewRepoName.git`

Answer (score 0):

> now I created new repo still i am unable to commit

First, your error is when you want to push your commits to the remote GitHub repo, not when you commit.
You are able to commit: it is a local operation which does not care about the remote repo.

But try:

```
cd /path/to/local/repo
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/4bhishekKasam/Passportjs.git
```

(or `git remote add origin ...`, if you didn't set `origin` before)

Then your `git push -u origin master` will work.